# Does Monero have any mobile wallets available?

Tags: security, privacy, mobile, android-wallet, ios-wallet

Mobile usage is growing very fast worldwide. Monero transactions should be easy to conduct from any device

1. Does Monero have any Android or iOS wallets available?
2. If there are no mobile wallets today, are there any in development?
3. What unique privacy or security concerns do Monero mobile wallets have?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Does Monero have any Android or iOS wallets available?**

No Monero iOS or Android wallet currently existed in the Apple App Store or Google Play Store for a long time with the custodial [Freewallet](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4tkxxe/apple_approves_freewallet_adds_ethereum_bitcoin/) exception related to [Bytecoin/Minergate](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/which-entities-are-related-to-bytecoin-and-minergate). This wallet has been marked as *distrusted by the Monero community* in the [Monero Reddit wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/wiki/avoid):

> Freewallet – Please read through the many threads out there regarding Freewallet, and the selective scam that it plays on its unsuspecting users

**If there are no mobile wallets today, are there any in development?**

Monero Research Lab researcher and developer Shen Noether, aka NobleSir created beta wallets for both [Android](https://github.com/ShenNoether/MiniNeroDroid) and [Windows 10](https://github.com/ShenNoether/MiniNeroUniversal) in 2016 but their respective GitHub pages were closed following his MRL departure. Jaxx spent some time working on [integrating Monero](http://www.nasdaq.com/article/monero-coming-jaxx-wallets-including-ios-with-apples-blessing-cm692114) (for both Android and iOS) but [temporarily halted](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5rjll8/looks_like_monero_wont_be_in_jaxx_for_a_while/) Monero development for technical reasons (development pre RingCT needed to be altered after the v4 fork in January 2017. [Reportedly](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6cmowc/jaxx_to_include_ripple_monero_tether_and_dozens/) they have now resumed plans to integrate Monero.

Currently [Android development](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4637/121) is the furthest along for:

- [Coinomi](https://twitter.com/CoinomiWallet/status/907696062533652480) is reportedly close to completion and in the testing phase
- [MyMonero](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6fd2l9/update_about_mymonero_mobile_wallet/diifjfd/) is close to complete pending porting iOS code into the Android JavaScript App. Its source code can be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js).
- [Official GUI](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/780) source code can be tested now, with no release dates known at this time
- [Monerujo](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerujo) is an [open source app](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet) now available for beta testing in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.m2049r.xmrwallet). Following more testing and bug fixes its developer also plans to add it to [F-Droid](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/71wysb/update_monerujo_beta_now_on_google_play_store/dne8ec3/).

Late stage iOS development has been reported for iOS by:

- [MyMonero](https://monerobase.com/wiki/DevMeeting_2017-09-17) is complete pending a DUNS number required for Apple App Store approval and a possible small delay to ensure simultaneous cross platform release
- [XWallet](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6o72am/announcement_x_wallet_for_monero_is_coming_soon/dlrbzhq/) is waiting for iOS approval

**What unique privacy or security concerns do Monero mobile wallets have?**

Privacy concerns are present anytime you rely on the full node of a [3rd party instead of running your own](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-privacy-or-security-trade-offs-are-associated-with-not-running-your-own-ful). Some of the mobile wallets listed above [allow users to connect to their own server](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6003/monerujo-deamon-adress).

Security risks are highest among closed source mobile applications and those which provide your private keys to a third party. Implementation related errors can occur in any application but are more common with apps that have not received sufficient testing, peer review or that require users to complete complicated setup procedure.

Comment: Shen closed his git account, monero-wallet-gui is/will be able to run on Android / IOS, and mymonero will be opensourced

Answer (score 6):

With respect to freewallet on iOS, I'd like to add a personal experience.  I sent a small amount of XMR to this wallet a few weeks ago and it took 2 days for the wallet to reflect a balance, this despite the transaction being confirmed and written to a block.  Only after contacting their support did my XMR magically appear.  No explanation or reply was given to me.

I would not use this wallet if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

Web wallet http://mymonero.com is excellent for mobile.

Update: MyMonero is zero-trust wallet, no one but you own your private keys. It has responsive markup which fits into any mobile phone. I recommend this web wallet for daily usage.

Comment: It would help if you could expand on this answer. For example you could describe mobile UI formatting, ease of you, security, etc. and compare it with the other mobile options

Comment: MyMonero is zero-trust wallet, no one but you own your private keys. It has responsive markup which fits into any mobile phone. I recommend this web wallet for daily usage.

Comment: can you edit your answer to add that additional information instead of leaving it in the comments?