# What is the roadmap for a GUI wallet?

Tags: mobile, monero-wallet-gui, third-party-wallets

I love Monero and always have but the lack of a GUI wallet is a huge issue for people actually trying to use the currency in the real world.  What is the plan for a GUI wallet on all platforms including mobile?

Obviously there is money and interest out there and I want XMR to succeed, so this seems like the next logical leap.

Comment: The GUI wallet is pretty much ready. You can run it now.

Answer (score 9):

> What is the plan for a GUI wallet on all platforms including mobile?

The "official" GUI is [funded](https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/2476/the-official-qt-gui-project) and in active development and getting closer to completion. Open issues can be tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue)

There are some existing mobile wallet options (in beta) with [more on the way](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/897/does-monero-have-any-mobile-wallets-available)