# What are some reliable public monero nodes one can connect to using their Monerujo app?

Tags: nodes, android-wallet, monerujo

Many times some public nodes are down and I don't want to connect to non-known public ones as shown in the monerujo app. Or does it not provide a risk at all?

What are some public monero nodes one can use?

And is there a risk of connecting to the nodes that show up in monerujo app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://node.pwned.systems/ has a listing of nodes you could use, updated every 20 minutes.

If you like to use DNS: `node.moneroworld.com:18089`

To understand the risks, [read this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/84810s/psa_tracing_attacks_could_be_possible_when_using/) and [this link](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-privacy-or-security-trade-offs-are-associated-with-not-running-your-own-ful/86#86).

Comment: Also see: https://moneroworld.com/#nodes