# Is it safe to use a remote node?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, remote-node

I started using Monero from now and my laptop takes a lot of time to download the blockchain. Also, my SSD is small and nearly full.

I was reading about the use of a remote node to sync my wallet, but I'm guessing if it is safe or not. Should I use any caution?

Regards.

Comment: Related -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-privacy-or-security-trade-offs-are-associated-with-not-running-your-own-ful/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safety is a scale relative to your requirements. If the remote node is not your own remote node, you are trusting that remote node to a) not censor you by not relaying transactions or send you blocks from the main chain and b) not to log your IP address.

Therefore it's always preferable to use your own node (local or remote). If you're happy with the risks above, it safe to use public remote nodes.