# How does a wallet using a remote node select ring members?

Tags: privacy, ring-signatures, nodes

If I'm going to have decoys in my transactions, I need to know about them somehow. How does Monero prevent the remote node I'm connected to from feeding me known ring members, effectively ruining that part of Monero's privacy?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed *one* of the problems with using a public remote node controlled by someone else. There is some related information in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/84/7493).

For optimal privacy one should use their own node (whether local or remote).

Comment: I don't quite understand that answer since it says it's since been fixed. Can you add more clarity to your answer?

Comment: One particular aspect was fixed with the linked PR - leaking to a remote node which tx in a block is destined for you. This is different than asking a node for output indices to use as potential ring members.