# From a privacy perspective, what does wallet reveal to node when it syncs and broadcasts transactions?

Tags: tor

Asking because Tor support (using `torsocks`) is unstable. Trying to wrap my mind around the privacy implications of using a public node vs a self-hosted private node (without routing connections through Tor).

Perhaps these connections are priavte by design...

Comment: You could run a packet capture.  Might need to set up a break and inspect if its a ssl/tls connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What privacy or security trade offs are associated with not running your own full node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-privacy-or-security-trade-offs-are-associated-with-not-running-your-own-ful)